# How to measure the correlation between "spirituality" and the susceptibility to false memories?

Tags: memory, reference-request, terminology, religion

Is there a measurement to correlate "spirituality" (how religious one is) to susceptibility to false memories? What papers or keywords should we look for?

Comment: Why do you want to do this research?

Comment: it's a creative direction my gf is taking in her undergraduate project in psychology :)

Comment: if your girlfriend has any result on this, please come back and share what you know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is the field [cognitive science of religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_science_of_religion):

> Cognitive science of religion is the study of religious thought and behavior from the perspective of the cognitive and evolutionary sciences. The field employs methods and theories from a very broad range of disciplines, including: cognitive psychology, evolutionary psychology, cognitive anthropology, artificial intelligence, neurotheology, developmental psychology, and archaeology. Scholars in this field seek to explain how human minds acquire, generate, and transmit religious thoughts, practices, and schemas by means of ordinary cognitive capacities.

Follow up resources:

- [International Association for the Cognitive Science of Religion (IACSR)](http://www.iacsr.com/)
- [Journal for the Cognitive Science of Religion](https://journals.equinoxpub.com/index.php/JCSR)